# Bucle duplicado en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

tengo un problema con este carrito de compras hecho en javascript que encontré por ahí.

Tengo una lista de productos y cada producto debe tener un opción de personalizar el producto, ya sea color, tamaño, etc.

Adjunto imágenes:

Aquí por ejemplo elijo los colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí elijo los tamaños:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de agregar ambos productos a mi carrito se añade efectivamente las personalizaciones que elegí para cada producto

**El problema es el siguiente:** Las personalizaciones se repiten desde el segundo producto.

**Por ejemplo:**

- Para el producto 1 "Box testing demo": Elegí los colores (Azul y verde)
- Para el producto 2 "Other box testing": Elegí los tamaños (Pequeño y grande)

Pero, en mi carrito en el segundo producto me aparece los colores + los tamaños siendo que debían ir por separado para cada producto.

- En producto 1 debe ir: Verde, azul.
- En producto 2 debe ir: Pequeño, grande (pero se agrega verde, azul, pequeño, grande)
- Si elijo un producto 3 pasaría esto: "Verde, azul, pequeño, grande, naranja, manzana, por ejemplo." y así sucesivamente.

Adjunto carrito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código "namevar" es la variable de las personalizaciones:

```
var shoppingCart = (function() {
    cart = [];
    
    function Item(name, namevar, price, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.namevar = namevar;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
    }
    var obj = {};

    obj.addItemToCart = function(name, namevar, price, count) {
        for(var item in cart) {
            if(cart[item].name === name) {
                cart[item].count ++;
                saveCart();
                return;
            }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, namevar, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    }
    return obj;
})();

$('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var namevar = $(this).data('namevar');
    var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, namevar, price, 1);
    displayCart();
});

function displayCart() { 
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var pedidoArray = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var showPedidoList = shoppingCart.listCart(); 
    var output = ""; 
    var pedido = ""; 
    var resumen = "";

    for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<div class='col-md-12' style='padding:0!important;'>"
                    + "<span class='menu_item title'>"
                        + "<div>"
                            + "<p style='text-align: center;margin:0'>Cantidad:</p>"
                            + "<span class='cantidadAdd'>"
                                + "<button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn_1 outline' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' style='border: 0;font-size:18px;font-weight:600'>-</button>"
                                + "<input type='number' class='item-count' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
                                + "<button class='plus-item btn_1 outline' input-group-addon' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' style='border: 0;font-size:18px;font-weight:600'>+</button>"
                            + "</span>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "<h3 style='width: 75%;'><b>x"+ cartArray[i].count +"</b> "+ cartArray[i].name +"</h3>"
                        + "<p style='margin:7px 0;width: 75%;'>"+ cartArray[i].namevar +"</p>"
                        + "<strong style='color: gray'>₲ "+ cartArray[i].price.toLocaleString('es-PY') +" c/u</strong><br>"
                    + "</span>"
                + "</div>";
        }
            $('.show-pedido').html(pedido);
            $('.show-cart').html(output);
            $('.showPedidoList').html(resumen);
            $('.totalSend > input').val(shoppingCart.totalCart());
            $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
            $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
    }
    $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        var count = Number($(this).val());
        shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
        displayCart();
    });
displayCart();
```

En handlebars tengo esto:

```
<div class="content">
    <div>
        {{{descripcion.full}}}
        {{#each variantes}}
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="{{{name}}}-{{{../name}}}" class="container_check">
                    {{{name}}}
                    <span>
                        {{#if precio}}+ ₲ {{{numberFormat precio}}}{{else}}{{/if}}
                    </span>                 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{{name}}}" id="{{{name}}}-{{{../name}}}" value="{{{name}}}"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {{/each}}
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row small-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button
                style="font-size: 19px;"
                data-name="{{name}}"
                data-price="{{precio}}"
                data-namevar=""
                class="add-to-cart btn_1 gradient medium full-width">
                <i class="icon_bag_alt"></i> Agregar (₲ {{{numberFormat precio}}})
            </button>
            <p class="text-center" style="color:gray;margin:5px 0 0 0;font-size:12px">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y también tengo esto:

```
    // find and retrieve all <input> elements of
    // 'type=checkbox':
    var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    // use the on() method to bind the anonymous function
    // as the event-handler of the 'change' event:
    checkboxes.on('change', function() {
        // update the 'data-namevar' element's text:
        $("button").attr('data-namevar', function() {
            return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                return this.name;
            }).get().join(', ') + '.';
        });
    });
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Probablemente el error es al seleccionar las propiedades, que no estés limpiando los atributos de datos y se suman a los del primer elemento que agregaste.

Comment: Sí, ahora que lo dices tal vez ese sea el error. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Parece que el error está en cartArray, pero no se ve el método shoppingCart.listCart() que es el que crea cartArray. Yo revisaría ese método.

Comment: List cart realiza esto:
`// List cart
 obj.listCart = function() {
  var cartCopy = [];
  for(i in cart) {
   item = cart[i];
   itemCopy = {};
   for(p in item) {
    itemCopy[p] = item[p];
   }
   itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toLocaleString('es-PY');
   cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
  }
  return cartCopy;
 }
 return obj;`